# Store million of images : File system or NoSQL?

Tags: mongodb, image, postgresql, filesystems, nosql

I have 3 Go of jpg images ( 150px * 150 px ,  < 10k )

I have divided my folder into subfolders to be able to see them in windows explorer...
- when I zip or unzip, it takes more than 10 hours
- when I load these pictures on amazon s3, it's the nightmare,...

So I wonder ! what about a NoSQL database like for example PostgreSQL ? I would store all my picture in a JSON format { 'name' : 'image01.jpg', '12WFHSKFHDKSFFISNKSADNXKLSJ......KDJHHDJSHFGF' }

This would be perfect to store all picture in 1 unique file (no need to zip or unzip) and very simple to manage

I have seen that it was possible with mongodb (something like $gridFS->storeFile("FileName.jpg", array("_id" => $id)); )

It seems that it's not possible to do that with Postgresql... I can find anything about storing image in postgres (JSON)

Ok I'm lost,... Help :(

Comment: 1) PostgreSQL is **not** NoSQL DBMS. 2) [Binary Data Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) if you interesting in PostgreSQL. 3) As I know, MongoDB have limitation for object size (probably I mistaken but it is very simple to find out it)

Comment: but Postgres has NoSQL function with JSON, Hstore etc... so why do you say that it's not NoSQL ? I thought it was SQL and NoSQL ... (see white paper "Using the NoSQL Capabilities in Postgres")

Answer (score 3):

Well PostgreSQL is first of all relational database, as Abelisto wrote. However recently it have introduced lots of useful noSQL additions, including effective JSON storage and indexing support.

If you interested in storing in PostgreSQL, you can for sure use JSON. In this case for content of file simply convert its content to Base64 encoding and during read perform decoding.

But as long as you have strict document structure it is better to introduce a table with structure like [name varchar(255), content bytea],  and store your file in table. This will not force you to encode/decode your file in Base64 encoding - you will simply get your content as byte array.

Comment: thx for the answer ! If I store in Json using Base64, the database will be bigger that bytea right ? (16KB -> ceil(16*1024/3)*4 = 21848 bytes long) .. Is there an other encoding that I can use to reduce the size rather that increase it ?

Comment: Philippos, regarding usage of storage you are right. Bytearray to Base64 and then into JSON with.idex on JSON content... in contrast to name string with index on it, and bytea field of its content. The second option is faster, and will use a bit less space.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will not work.

> store all picture in 1 unique file

In PostgreSQL, even if you use JSON data types, you are still limited to roughly a GB size.

Let me ask you another question: is there a specific reason why you store the images in a database - relational or NoSQL? This seems to be a hefty overhead every time you have to fetch one of the images.

Comment: You can't store 2,6GB in a single field in PostgreSQL. And: how will you ever work on the pictures, if they are compressed?

Comment: He obviously was going to store each picture as a separate RECORD of json type, not all pics in a single record of course.

Answer (score 0):

Pros of the MongoDB implementation for this task would be easy replication of your data over multiple servers and sharding which would allow easy horizontal scaling (if you are out of disk space, simply deploy one more shard). Question is, how performant MongoDB would be compared to other noSQL solutions. Also keep in mind that you can not store images of individual size >16 Mb in straight Mongo, but with GridFS you can of course bypass this limitation. So if your files are all smaller than the 16 MB BSON Document Size limit, consider storing the file manually within a single document instead of using GridFS (BinData data type can be leveraged for this),